# Restrict the number of input characters in Tk entry widget

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, gtkentry

In TCL how can I restrict the number of input characters in an `entry` widget?

I have a TCL field in which a user can enter some text, I wish to restrict the length of the text (e.g. not more than 30 characters).

Are there any options for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry validation callback is the way, and the `%P` substitution is the key. From [the docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/entry.htm#M25):

> **%P**
>   The value of the entry if the edit is allowed. If you are configuring the entry widget to have a new textvariable, this will be the value of that textvariable.

This means we do just this:

```
pack [entry .e -width 50 -validate all -validatecommand {
    expr {[string length %P] <= 30}
}]
```

There you go, you will be unable to do any edit to the widget which makes its length go over 30. (It might be best to also add an `-invalidcommand` specification so that the user can find out what happened.)

Comment: Thanks for short and sweet solution :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one, but you can use validation on the entry widget as follows:

```
package require Tk

pack [entry .e -validate all -validatecommand {max_length %s 30 %d}]

proc max_length {val max act} {
  if {[string length $val] >= $max && $act == 1} {
    return 0
  }
  return 1
}
```

The entry box will try to validate each entry, and passes the current string `%s` and the action `%d` to the `proc` named `max_length`

Within this proc, the length and action is checked for. If the length is above 30 and the action is `1` (meaning an insertion), then the proc will return 0 thus stopping any more insertion.

Comment: What if the user clicks on the first character and then types when there are already 30 characters? What if they paste 40 characters at position 29?

Comment: @1336087 Thanks! Lol, I guess I over-thought about it. Never used `%P` before, so thanks for your question; I learned something new too :)